# How to have a better wording for the meaning of "confirm column to show up"

Tags: website-design, wording, confirmation

I'm designing data table project, here is pop-up confirm window. Any suggestions on a better wording for the meaning of "confirm column to show up"?
[image]

Comment: try 'visible' - as in 'Confirm visible columns'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about...

> ## Select Columns for Publication
>
> Check the columns you wish to show in the published table. Unchecked columns will not be shown.

(I would even go so far as to say the second sentence is implied,  and thus unnecessary.)